# On mouseover one state, change colors of other states with d3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I think my title sums up my question. If I hover the mouse over one state in a d3 map, how do I change the colors of a preset group of other states?

I could do something like..

```
.on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
   if this == (one of the present map selections){
     d3.select({theotherdataname}}.parentNode.appendChild({{theotherdataname??}})).transition().duration(300)
            .style({'stroke-opacity':1,'stroke':'#F00'});
         } 
      }
 });
```

OK that is terrible code. But I wanted to offer something to start.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Maybe I need to completely update the chart data?

Comment: All you should need to do is select all the paths(?) and filter the one for the current state. There's no need to append new elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all other states using D3's `filter` method, then apply styles.

http://devdocs.io/d3/selections#filter

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yejuwa/2/edit

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

  d3.select('#specific').on('mouseover', function(d, i) {

    var currentState = this;
    var thoseStates = d3
      .selectAll('.those')[0]
      .filter(function(state) {
        return state !== currentState;
      });

    d3.selectAll(thoseStates)
      .transition()
      .duration(300)
      .style({
        'stroke-opacity': 1,
        'stroke': '#f00'
      });

  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<body>

  <svg width="150" height="150">
    <circle id="specific" class="these" cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="yellow" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
  </svg>

  <svg width="150" height="150">
    <rect class="those" width="50" height="50" fill="pink" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" />
  </svg>

</body>
```

Comment: Excellent idea. I'd forgotten about D3's `filter`.

Comment: @Gilsha Could you explain why you use the array[0] specifier in: .selectAll('.those')[0] ?

Comment: Also there seems to be a double D3.selectall on "thosestates" in the second selection. we'd probably want to assign d3 to .those and then retuse the var.